# Bind two UI elements of two dynamically loaded xaml files

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm still grasping for a better formulation of the question. This is what I have so far:

A custom class that contains a list of modules, with some modules being a specialized version of the generic module

```
[Serializable]
class ModuleList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Module> Items
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    public ModuleList()
    { 
       Items = new ObservableCollection<Module>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Module : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string name;
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return this.name;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.name != value)
         {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
         }
      }
   }
   [field: NonSerialized]
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
      if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
   }
}

[Serializable]
class SpecializedModule : Module
{
   public SpecializedModule()
   {
      mode = false;
   }

   private bool mode;
   public bool Mode
   {
      get
      {
         return this.mode;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.mode != value)
         {
            this.mode = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The items list serves as `ItemSource` for a `ListView`. Selecting an item on the list loads the corresponding .xaml using `XamlReader`. A `System.Windows.Control.Grid`, is used as a container for the module-specific UI. "Normal" binding works as expected by setting the data context of the grid to the module list

```
switch (it.ModID)
{
   case "SOMEMODID":
      loadGrid("somemodule.xaml");
      break;
   default:
      loadGrid("_dummy.xaml");
      break;
}
grpModCfg.DataContext = modListSel;
```

then setting the `DataContext` of the subgrid to the respective module using a converter

```
public class ModuleListToModuleConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
         if (value is ModuleList)
         {
            ModuleList modList = value as ModuleList;

            int idx = modList.getItemIndex(parameter as string);
            if (idx != -1)
            {
               return modList.Items[idx];
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            return null;
         }
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object obj, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
```

An example .xaml:

```
<Grid Name="grdSomeMod" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModCfg;assembly=ModCfg" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      d:DesignHeight="395" 
      d:DesignWidth="480" >
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:ModuleListToModuleConverter x:Key="modlistConverter" />
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Grid.DataContext>
      <Binding Converter="{StaticResource modlistConverter}" ConverterParameter="SOMEMODEID" />
   </Grid.DataContext>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <CheckBox Content="Some Parameter" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyOfSomeModule}" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="chkSomePar" />
</Grid>
```

This works just fine for binding the properties of a specific module. However, I also have dependencies on properties of other modules, for example, so I need something like

- CheckBoxA.IsChecked = moduleA.SomeProperty
- CheckBoxB.IsEnabled = moduleB is in the list && moduleB.SomeOtherProperty == true/false

What I tried so far:

- approach A

  - leave the `DataContext` set to my modules list so that I have access to all of them
  - set the context per element, so that those that need to access another module have the context
  - problem: once I set the context to one module, I can't access the other, so binding `IsEnabled`to a property of moduleA and `IsChecked`to a property of module B is impossible.
- approach B

  - use a converter w/ parameter specifying which module and which property to search for (comma separated, then split in converter)
  - problem: it works for IsEnabled, but IsChecked complains about needing a Path because of two-way binding and I can't seem to be able to find one that works.

XAML for approach A:

```
<Grid Name="grdSomeMod" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModCfg;assembly=ModCfg" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      d:DesignHeight="395" 
      d:DesignWidth="480" >
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:ModuleListToModuleConverter x:Key="modlistConverter" />
   </Grid.Resources>

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <CheckBox Content="Some Parameter" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyOfSomeModule}" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="chkSomePar>
      <CheckBox.DataContext>
         <Binding Converter="{StaticResource modlistConverter}" ConverterParameter="SOMEMODEID" />
      </Checkbox.DataContext>
   </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

XAML for approach B:

```
<Grid Name="grdSomeMod" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModCfg;assembly=ModCfg" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      d:DesignHeight="395" 
      d:DesignWidth="480" >
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:ModuleListToModuleConverter x:Key="modlistConverter" />
      <local:ModuleListToModuleDefineConverter x:Key="defBinaryConverter" />
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Grid.DataContext>
      <Binding Converter="{StaticResource modlistConverter}" ConverterParameter="SOMEMODEID" />
   </Grid.DataContext>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <CheckBox Content="Some Parameter" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyOfSomeModule}" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="chkSomePar">

      <CheckBox.IsChecked>
         <!--not working atm-->
         <Binding Path="." Converter="{StaticResource defBinaryConverter}" ConverterParameter="SOMEMODID,SomeProperty"  />
      </CheckBox.IsChecked>
      <CheckBox.IsEnabled>
         <Binding Converter="{StaticResource defBinaryConverter}" ConverterParameter="SOMEOTHERMODID,SomeOtherProperty"  />
      </CheckBox.IsEnabled>
   </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

And the converter for approach B:

```
public class ModuleListToModuleDefineConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (value is ModuleList)
      {
         ModuleList modlist = value as ModuleList;
         string paramList = parameter as string;
         string[] pars = paramList.Split(',');
         int idx = modlist.getItemIndex(pars[0]);
         if (idx != -1)
         {
            switch (pars[0])
            {
               case "SOMEMODID":
                  switch (pars[1])
                  {
                     case "SomeProperty":
                        return (modlist.Items[idx] as SomeModule).C0x10;
                  }
                  break;
               case "SOMEOTHERMODID":
                  switch (pars[1])
                  {
                     case "SomeOtherProperty":
                        return (modlist.Items[idx] as SomeOtherMod).SomeOtherProperty;
                  }
                  break;
            }
         }
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object obj, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

That's quite a lot of code, but it's also a problem I've been trying to solve for about a week now, and I feel like I'm getting really close, but possible overlooking something.

Maybe there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I find this question unclear. E.g. why load XAML dynamically? Why not just have appropriate templates as resources you reference as needed? Why is the data context not simply already the module instance for which the template was loaded/referenced? There's a big code dump above, but it's incomplete and at the same time includes things that don't seem strictly necessary for the question. Please read [mcve] for advice on how to provide a good code example. Please state specifically what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I should have probably stated that I'm also rather new to WPF, so my problems might be simply because I lack knowledge about the matter. Loading XAML dynamically seemed like the best way to not have one huge XAML with all the modules in it. I don't see how loading the pages from a resource is different than loading from file in my case. If the data context of each module is set to the module from the start, there is no way to access another module's properties to map the dependencies as far as I can tell - and this is my problem.

Comment: _"I don't see how loading the pages from a resource is different than loading from file in my case"_ -- if you have defined your templates as resources, then you can take advantage of existing templating features in WPF rather than having to write code-behind to match a template with data types. As for the rest, unfortunately your question isn't making clear what you mean by "access another module's properties to map the dependencies". A template should only need to access the properties of the module type for which it's defined.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Thanks for the idea about the resources, it simplified the loading for me significantly. I've also realized a few other logical mistakes I had made, so I was managed to come up with a solution. Sorry for the unclear formulation of the question, I'll try to be clearer next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that even if I managed to map my dependencies in XAML the way I wanted to, I'd have no way to pass them to the C# code. For example, even if a feature is disabled in the GUI, I have no way of knowing that in my module object. So my solution is to add an additional property for those properties having a dependency, map that property to the "IsEnabled", and update the value from within the object after the XAML is loaded. Using the snippets I posted in my question, the change for me is

```
[Serializable]
class SpecializedModule : Module
{
   public SpecializedModule()
   {
      mode = false;
   }

   private bool mode;
   public bool Mode
   {
      get
      {
         return this.mode;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.mode != value)
         {
            this.mode = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
         }
      }

   private bool modeEn;
   public bool ModeEn
   {
      get
      {
         return this.modeEn;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.modeEn != value)
         {
            this.modeEn = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ModeEn");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The data context of the individual XAML is now set to the respective module, so the binding is straightforward.

```
<CheckBox Content="Some Parameter" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyOfSomeModule}" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="chkSomePar" IsChecked="{Binding Mode}" IsEnabled="{Binding ModeEn}" />
```

Now all I have to do is to write a function that checks if the module my feature depends on is in the list and call it when the user selects an item.

```
switch (it.ModID)
{
   case "SOMEMODID":
      loadGrid("somemodule.xaml");
      break;
   default:
      loadGrid("_dummy.xaml");
      break;
}
grpModCfg.DataContext = modListSel;
modList.refreshDependencies();
```

And the refresh function would looks something like

```
public void refreshDependencies()
{
   foreach (Module mod in this.Items)
   {
      int idx = -1;
      switch (mod.ModID)
      { 
         case "SOMEMODID":
            // Mode depends on SOMEOTHERMODID
            idx = this.modList.getItemIndex("SOMEOTHERMODID");
            if (idx != -1)
            {
               (mod as SomeModule).ModeEn = (this.Items[idx] as SomeOtherModule).SomeOtherProperty;
            }
            else
            {
               (mod as SomeModule).ModeEn = false;
            }
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

So now I have access to all of my modules in the code and the GUI reflects the state of the objects.

**EDIT:**

I've also realized that editing the individual XAML files outside of code doesn't make any sense, since the C# code would have to changed anyway, so I followed the advice of Peter Duniho and switched to loading the individual XAML files as resources. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346593(v=vs.110).aspx) helped me in the process, so now the loading part of the code is reduced to

```
loadGrid(it.ModID);
grpModCfg.DataContext = it;
modList.refreshDependencies();
```